# Could not find file error after passing File.Exists check

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this code, it checks if a photo exists and if it has been created within the past 14 days. The issue I am finding is that the code is passing the `System.IO.File.Exists()` but then when I go to return the file at the end, it errors with a *"Could not find file"*. Anyone have any ideas? I am suspecting it is the way I am using Path.Combine?

##### EDIT

Managed to get it working by returning a filestream rather than a path.

```
var img = System.IO.File.OpenRead(PhotoPathAndFileName);

return File(img, "image/jpeg");
```

**

```
public IActionResult GetPhoto(string ID, int MaxHeight, int MaxWidth, bool isStudentImage = true)
    {
        var PhotoFileName = ID + "_" + MaxHeight.ToString() + "x" + MaxWidth.ToString() + ".jpg";

        var PhotoPathAndFileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\images\\App_Data\\_cacheIDPhoto", PhotoFileName);

        var FileExists = false;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(PhotoPathAndFileName))
        {
            var CreateDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(PhotoPathAndFileName);

            if (CreateDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(PhotoPathAndFileName);
            }
            else
            {
                FileExists = true;
            }
        }
        if (!FileExists)
        {

            PhotoPathAndFileName = CreatePhotoFile(Convert.ToInt32(ID), PhotoPathAndFileName, MaxWidth, MaxHeight, isStudentImage);
        }

        return File(PhotoPathAndFileName, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

Comment: After `System.IO.File.Delete(PhotoPathAndFileName);` you forgot to set `FileExists = false;`. So your code deleted the file and then tried to read it.

Comment: `FileExists` is already false at that point, @zaitsman.

Comment: Ouch, my bad. Then i guess we need to see what is going on inside `CreatePhotoFile`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. The simplest explanation is that `CreatePhotoFile` doesn't do what it says on the tin. _There is also a race condition, but that is edge case enough that I doubt it is your current issue._

Comment: The easiest way to validate that the problem is in `CreatePhotoFile` is to manually create a file where it is trying to find it so that `FileExists` is set to true and the manually placed file is read instead.

Comment: You've read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?view=netframework-4.8#remarks ? What is the **exact** value it is returning?

Comment: Also, what OS are you running this assembly on?

Comment: Just a nitpick, but might want to read the Microsoft guidelines for naming conventions in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't the `File` method expecting a virtual path? If so your absolute path in `PhotoPathAndFileName` wouldn't work.

Comment: Absolute path would work fine @Dirk

Comment: @mjwills It doesn't work with absolute path either. Only way that worked for me was the answer the OP posted.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working by returning a filestream rather than a path.

```
var img = System.IO.File.OpenRead(PhotoPathAndFileName);

return File(img, "image/jpeg");
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but rather a workaround. The reason as to why your code wasn't working is still elusive.

Comment: Rather a workaround that worked. Thanks for sharing @Kyle. Feel free to mark as answer.